# Symfony2 problems with PdoSessionHandler

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

I'm having some problems in my Symfony2 project to set up the parametes in config.yml to be able to use PdoSessionHandler correctly. The version of Symfony that Im using is 2.3.9

What Im trying to do is to store sessions in the database using the PdoSessionHandler.

I've followed the cookbook, but I'm having the following error in my config.yml

**There is no extension able to load the configuration for "session.handler.pdo"**

Is there another change or config that should be done to have effect?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added `session.handler.pdo` as a service definition (under `services:`) but as a configuration-definition/root-node in your `config.yml`.

That's why symfony can't find an extension for loading that non-existant configuration.

This will work:

```
services:
    session.handler.pdo: 
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler
        # ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I've found my mistake, I was adding the session.handler.pdo as new node in my config, and not as a service.